# JPA EntityManager with Hibernate - find and remove does not delete data from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Having trouble getting the following code to work...

I've got a `JpaTransactionManager` `txManager` autowired into this test. I know record with ID 39 *does* exist. It still exists at the end of the transactions, too...

```
    TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    A a = mock(A.class);
    when(a.getId()).thenReturn(Long.valueOf(39));
    sut.delete(a);
    txManager.commit(status);

    status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    a = sut.get(a.getId());
    txManager.commit(status);

    assertNull(a);
```

Code in class `A`:

```
public void delete(A a) {

    a = getEntityManager().find(A.class, a.getId());
    getEntityManager().remove(a);

}
```

Is there any reason the above assertNull check *always* fails? I cannot delete the object from my system no matter what I do - no error returned, and no issue with the delete reported. (As an aside, running a query directly in HQL *does* result in an update of the database...I just can't get it to work using the delete method supplied using JPA...)

Any assistance appreciated

Comment: Can we see the `getEntityManager()` code?

Comment: It's inserted using Spring, and works for every other scenario. Possible cause is that my `A` is the owning side of a `OneToOne` relationship, but that has no cascade options defined on it. Could this be the cause?

Comment: What I was wondering was, if `getEntityManager()` returned a new one each time you called it, whether you could `find()` with one and then `delete()` with another. Try calling `getEntityManager()` once, storing a reference to what you get back (`EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager()`), and then using that same reference to `find()` and `remove()` the entity.

Comment: Yeah - it doesn't do that. Spring creates the EntityManager object within the transaction boundaries. If I just call `remove` within the EntityManager, I get an error that I am trying to persist a detached entity. I appreciate your hint, but this isn't what's wrong unfortunately :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look into these Hibernate classes/methods:

```
org/hibernate/engine/spi/ActionQueue.java executeActions(), unScheduleDeletion()
org/hibernate/event/internal/DefaultPersistEventListener.java onPersist()
```

I had the same problem - not being able to remove an entity. In my case, entityManager had two entities in its 'context': a parent with a list of children entities (**cascade = CascadeType.ALL**) and a child (from the list) to remove. So when I was trying to remove a child, parent still had a link to it, which was causing Hibernate to 'unScheduleDeletion' upon flushing.

So here is the solution:

1. Add `orphanRemoval = true` to the collection of children
2. Create method `deleteChild(Child child) {child.setParent(null); children.remove(child);}`
3. Use this method to delete children

Looks like another solution is to remove cascading, so that merging of parent entity wouldn't cause saving all its children. Not quite sure here (haven't checked).

Also, as far as I remember, JPA spec describes this situation.

Comment: I had this same problem; I was trying to delete a child where the parent contained a list of children with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`. I didn't need this cascade so removed it, which caused `entityManager.remove` to delete my child row as expected.